# how to make my syncing bash script executable by a specific command like "mySync leftdir rightdir"?

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu

I'm creating a bash script for Unix in Ubuntu that synchronizes two directories.

i have already coded the sync program but the problem im facing is that i need to call my script by a command line :" **mySync  -r  leftdir rightdir** " or " **mySync  -i  leftdir rightdir** " and i dont seem to make it work.

**-r**    (recursive) will overwrite all duplicate folders.

**-i**     will overwrite the duplicate folders only if the user agrees

the question is how to make my script executable by a command ?

and also how can i make my script wait for the acceptance of the user before it overwrites if the " -i " command is chosen ?

thanks in advance for the help .

the Code is :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "hello,the directory must be on the Desktop. "
    read -p "Please enter your username: " x3

    read -p "First directory name: " x1
    read -p "Second directory name: " x2

    dir1="/home/$x3/Desktop/$x1/"
    dir2="/home/$x3/Desktop/$x2/"

    if [ -d $dir2 ]; then
    cd "$dir1"

    find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    [ -e "$dir2/$file" ] || echo "$file"
    done

    cp -rupv $dir2* $dir1

    else
    echo Path Not found.. Check network status
    fi


    if [ -d $dir1 ]; then
    cd "$dir2"
    find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    [ -e "$dir1/$file" ] || echo "$file"
    done

    cp -rupv $dir1* $dir2

    else
    echo Path Not found.. Check network status

    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why aren't you just using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)?

If you really want to do this yourself, I'd recommend using `getopt` or `getopts` to do options parsing.  Then you can control the execution based on these options...

To make a script executable you can to use chmod:

`$ chmod +x mySync`

Comment: I wanted to do it myself without rsync ,so I'll try getopt ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe a little??

If you are wanting to make your script to be executable by a command, Create a C wrapper
Like this

Make a folder in the /usr/ directory (assuming XXX) and copy the sh file there

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char string[512];
  strcpy(string, "");
  if(argc>=2){      //if argument exists
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        strcpy(string, strcat(strcat(string, argv[i]), " ") );
    }

            char cmd[512];
            system("cd /usr/XXX")
            strcpy(cmd, strcat("PROGRAM_NAME.sh ", string)); //note the SPACE
            system(cmd);
  }

  else{
    system("cd /usr/XXX")
    system("PRGRAM_NAME.sh");
  }
}
```

Its very roughly coded (compile with -std=c99) and then put both the sh file and the Compiled file in the /usr/XXX directory and now open .bashrc file and at the end put

```
export PATH="/usr/XXX:$PATH"
```

Now type in the command..

And if the command not working, revise it... If someone else answers it completely, the joy is lost (basically, I don't have enough courage to examine the file now)
**EDIT**
You need to source the .bashrc file by typing source .bashrc